# Synchronize Scroll position of ScrollView across all fragments inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, scrollview

So I have an activity with a view pager that inflates about 7 Fragments, and each fragment has a ScrollView inside it, I want to synchronize the scroll of all 7 scrollviews, so if the user scrolls to a position on fragment 3 and moves on to fragment 5 they should be at the exact same position, the scrollviews inflate the same children so the total height of the scrollview is constant throughout all 7 fragments.

I go some kind of system working, but its kind of a hit or miss, i get the scroll position of a list and broadcast the position and the fragment that is idle consumes the broadcast, and I save the position on the activity too so that the position can be requested in onResume of fragments that have not been inflated yet. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mParentScrollView.setScrollY(mParentActivity.getScrollPos());
}

@Override
public void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY) {
    mScrollListener.onScroll(y);
    mParentActivity.setScrollPos(y);
    if (callbackSwitch) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("ACTION_SCROLL");
        intent.putExtra("TRANSLATION", y);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
    callbackSwitch = true; //Switch to stop recursive calls
}

private BroadcastReceiver mTranslationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!isVisible) {
            int translation = intent.getIntExtra("TRANSLATION", 0);
            mParentScrollView.setScrollY(translation);
            callbackSwitch = false;
        }
    }
};
```

I wanted to know if there is a better and stable way of achieving something similar.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how elegant this solutions is, but it should do the trick. Extend `ViewPager` and override `onMeasure(int, int)` method.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (h > height) height = h;
    }
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

My custom `ViewPager` was inside of a `NestedScrollView` and both of child fragments **did not** contained any additional `ScrollView`s.